# RLS in Power BI not working for certain users?

Tags: powerbi

I have a weird issue with the Row Level Security in Power BI - for some users the RLS is working while for other it isn't.

Here is my situation:

1. I have a workspace in Power BI Service. All users are defined as "Viewers", including the user A and user C:

[image]

2. I have a Power BI dataset & report with 2 RLS roles:

- "Alles": a role with no filters
- "MA-Aus": a role with a filter that filters out the entire table "MA Auslastung":

[image]

3. I deployed the dataset & report to Power BI service and map the users to the RLS roles. I add user A and user C into the "MA-Aus" role. This means they shouldn't see any data from the "MA Auslastung" table:

[image]

4. I go to "Test as Role" to check if everything is working as expected:

- I test the "MA-Aus" role. No value is shown in the "MA Sollzeit". This is correct - the table is filtered out, so the measure is blank.

[image]

- I test the user A. No value is shown in the "MA Sollzeit". This is correct - the table is filtered out, so the measure is blank.

[image]

**- I test the user C. "MA Sollzeit" returns value. The filter is not applied, RLS is not working.**

[image]

What is happening here? Both users are configured correctly (viewers in the workspace, added to the role). For user A the RLS is working while for user C the filter from the role is not applied.